# How to send a TTL trigger signal remotely

Tags: electrical-engineering, electronics, signal

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I am an undergrad intern working on a semi-independent project in a lab, and no one here can really help me with this.
I am trying to control a lab instrument remotely, and it has a TTL trigger input (High=on, low =off). The port is D-sub 15 pol. One of the 15 pins is a ground pin, and another one is the TTL trigger input pin. The signal should be of pretty low frequency (<5Hz).

Any ideas on how to do this relatively cheaply and remotely? It wouldn't make much sense to leave a function generator attached to it all the time.
I could easily run a cable to a nearby computer.

Comment: Books have been written on the subject - many of them. A lot depends on what you mean by "cable" and "nearby."  Frequency of the trigger doesn't matter in your case, but the rise and fall times of the TTL trigger source are a concern. If you do have an otherwise idle computer you could just try it - there's a good chance it will work.

Comment: Search "USB GPIO adapter" in your favourite online shopping place. Use one of the GPIOs on the adapter. Some circuitry might be needed. If galvanic isolation is needed, you could use an opto-isolator.

Comment: A tricky way to get a GPIO on a computer used to be to use the RTS/CTS lines on a serial port, but computers don't have those any more.

Comment: Do you mean remotely like via the internet? Or remotely like from the other side of the room?